# Is the 2nd law of thermodynamics more of a likelihood than a law?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology, entropy, arrow-of-time

**Given enough time, even extremely unlikely events are certain to happen.** This includes spontaneous reduction in disorder.

As an example, given enough time, all the particles of a gas in a container are certain to coalesce in a corner.

If so, isn't the 2nd law of thermodynamics more of a likelihood than a law?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the second law of thermodynamics a "no-go" theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450313/)

Comment: [More discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156217).

Comment: I put my answer  in the duplicate

Comment: Likewise as anna v.